# How to determine if a paragraph has indentation in doc file when parsing the file using mammoth?

Tags: html, parsing, ms-word, docx, mammoth

How to determine if a paragraph has indentation in doc file when parsing the file using mammoth?

PS: I need to add a custom class using style maps on the indented element so that I can add my custom CSS for displaying the indentation in the browser.

Thanks in advance!

I have gone through the style map docs but what I have found is that you can add classes on the element only but not on condition that if the element has certain properties or not.